# How prove $\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}(a_{j}-a_{i}+1)^2+4\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}\le \frac{5n^2+6n+4}{4}$

Tags: inequality

**Question:**

> let $$0\le a_{1}\le a_{2}\le\cdots\le a_{n}\le 1$$ show that
>   $$\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}(a_{j}-a_{i}+1)^2+4\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}\le \begin{cases}
> \dfrac{5n^2+6n+4}{4}&n=2k\\
> \dfrac{5n^2+6n+5}{4}&n=2k+1
> \end{cases}$$

This problem is from  Maths exam test simulation.and I fell this  sum can't deal it.Thank you

Comment: trivially, this is bounded by $2n^2$.  You are trying to improve to slightly more than $\tfrac{5}{4}n^2$ using correlations in the $a_1, \dots, a_n$.

Comment: If I set $a_1 = \dots a_n = 0$ the left side is $\tfrac{1}{2}n^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Fix k. Assume that for $i\neq k$, $a_i$ is fixed. We want to maximize the LHS. It is an upwards facing quadratic in $a_k$, so attains it's maximum at the endpoints of the interval. Thus $a_k= a_{k-1},a_{k+1}$.

Hence, all of the $a_i$ are either 1 or 0, so you now have n+1 equations to evaluate to find the maximum. The max is achieved when they are split 'somewhat evenly', which explains why the even and odd case have different bounds.

---

Not at computer, can provide more details later if needed. But you should have enough to work it out.

Comment: if you post you solution,maybe have some +1

Comment: @math110 That's alright, I don't need the +1. If you want more details, you can work on this [similar problem](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/if-only-i-could-see-in-81-dimensions-this-would-be/?group=7e8JdfrqPKKg).

Comment: Hello, you link only have problem,not solution? https://brilliant.org/community-problem/if-only-i-could-see-in-81-dimensions-this-would-be/?group=7e8JdfrqPKKg

Comment: @chinamath I wrote up a solution.

Comment: @chinamath You will need to log in to view the solution discussion.